# JSON - No repeating table name

Tags: php, json

I have some problems with json..

I will let my code here, and i will show you what does it print to me, and what i need to be printed..

Well... this is my  code:

```
                //open connection to mysql db
                $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","3d") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

                //fetch table rows from mysql db
                $query = "SELECT team FROM hs";

                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

                //create an array
                $arr = array();
                while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $arr[] = $row;
                }

                echo json_encode($arr);

                //close the db connection
                mysqli_close($connection);
```

And it print me a json code, like:

**[{"team":"coco"},{"team":"dada"},{"team":"fafa"},{"team":"momo"}]**

My question is, how can i print a json code like this:

**{"team":[["coco"],["dodo"]...]}**

Another question is, how can i print a json code like this: (I want to group 2 teams, like a power of 2...

**{"team":[["coco","dada"],["fafa","momo"]]}**

Thank you, and have a nice day...

Comment: The problem isn't with the JSON, it's with the PHP. If you make a PHP associative array where the entries are numerically-indexed arrays, you'll solve your problem. Right now, you're including the entire row. No shock, then, that the entire row shows up in your result.

Comment: Honestly I think you need to look at [Introducing JSON](http://json.org/) so that you understand what you are asking, as some of it just does not make sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form a proper array in your php

```
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","3d") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$query = "SELECT team FROM hs";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$arr = $new_arr = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $arr[] = $row['team'];
}

shuffle($arr);
$new_arr['team'] = array_chunk($arr, 2);

echo json_encode($new_arr);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is getting printed is a json array which consists of JSON objects hence you see the result like:

[{"team":"coco"},{"team":"dada"},{"team":"fafa"},{"team":"momo"}]

What I would suggest is, you should create a json array and keep adding json objects to it.

```
JSONArray team = new JSONArray();
team.add("coco");
team.add("dodo");
```

and so on.

Coming to your second doubt, create json arrays which will contain pairs of elements such as coco and dodo in one, foo and bar in other. Let's call these arrays arr1 and arr2.

Now create the main JSON array named team and do the following:

```
team.put(arr1);
team.put(arr2);
```

And you'll see the result you want. Do ask for clarifications if any. :)

Comment: Errr what is a JSONArray? We are talking PHP here remember.

Comment: I understand you, but i'm trying to create a tournament gaming bracket, and there will be 32+ teams, that means i should make an "add" for every team... I want to find a code, to json my sql database in something like this: {"team":[["coco"],["dodo"],["fafa"],["momo"]]}..